# fullcalendar - TypeError: b._start is undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, fullcalendar

I am using `FullCalendar v2.6.0`.

I am able to create a new event and render the same. But if i update the event, i get below error:-

```
TypeError: b._start is undefined

...=c.allDay&&(c.allDay=b.allDay),u(c),f={start:b._start.clone(),end:b._end?b._end....
```

**Javascript code**

```
var eventRequestProperties = {
                "startDate": new Date($('#appStartTime').val()),
                "endDate": new Date($('#appEndTime').val()),
                "title": $('#myEventName').val(),
                "description": $('#myEventdescription').val(),
                "allDay": ($('#appAllDay').val() == "true"),
                "id":evtId
           }

 $.ajax({
             url: '/changeEvent/updateEvent',
             type: 'POST',
             dataType: 'json',
             data: JSON.stringify(eventRequestProperties),
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             success: function(response) {
                 $("#calendar").fullCalendar('updateEvent',response,true);
             }
         });
```

Ajax call is fired to my spring controller, i just set the properties and send back the pojo object as response. Response attached as image.

[image]

```
class EventRequestProperties {

    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private String description;

    private String endDate;

    private String startDate;

    private boolean allDay;

}
```

Also when i load events first time from server, i again face similar issue, this time:

```
TypeError: a.start is undefined

...unction v(a){null==a.allDay&&(a.allDay=!(a.start.hasTime()||a.end&&a.end.hasTime...
```

**code**

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/shootSchedule/changeEvent/loadEvents',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(eventRequestProperties),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(response) {
            var events = [];
            events = response.myEvents; 
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent',events,true);
        }
    });
```

here events is array like below:

```
 [Object { id=8,  title="lunchdf",  description="lunch",  more...}]
```

instead of `events`, if i do `events[0]`, it works fine and event is displayed.

Comment: Did you fix it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

In fullcalendar.js, clientEvents method return array of event , even if we mention idorFilter. So that we need to use index with event[0] as you did:

```
                event = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents',response.event.id);
                event = $.extend(event[0],response.event);                    
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'updateEvent', event);
```